# How do I make elements in Vertical BoxSizer closer together?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, sizer, static-text

Is there a way to force the BoxSizer to display its elements with a specific gap between them? (closer to each other rather than further)

I'm trying to find a way to display 5 StaticText elements closer together so they fit in a small panel, but am only able to fit 4 elements
There clearly is space for 5 StaticTexts if they were closer to eachother
[image: There clearly is space for 5 StaticTexts if they were closer to eachother]

I assume I could also just make it a single static text with lines but am trying to keep each line as a different object

Comment: could you please post some code?

Comment: Just set the border pixels to 0 when adding the widgets.

Comment: If you're having no luck with the sizer padding, try changing the font size for those items in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Each static text has a "best size" which follows the native platform guidelines. The obvious advice when intending to modify that is not to do it.

But if you feel that you really must...

You can get the height (see `GetSize`) of the small panel that needs to fit all of them, divide it by 5 and set the height of each static text to the result, i.e. `aStaticText->SetSize(-1, smallPanelHeight/5);`

Another way could be to set a smaller font for each static text and let it adjust its "best size" accordingly. You will probably need to try a few font sizes before you decide which one will be best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is not possible. The layout engine takes into account the largest string size, plus a small margin so it can be clearly seen.

You could try adding between strings a fixed space by [AddSpacer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.BoxSizer.html#wx.BoxSizer.AddSpacer) passing a negative value. This is a dirty hack I haven't tested.